# Jmeter GIT - CI Execution and threshold values

Tags: git, jmeter, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am having a Jmeter test in GIT CI and able to execute the test , When trying to fail the pipeline due to failure in test, am running out of solutions in GIT-CI. Any suggestions/solution to fail the pipeline in GIT-CI based on the Jmeter test would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In order to mark your test as failed the JMeter job must return a non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), if you need to mark the job as failed on **any** sampler failure - just add a [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Test Plan and use the following code:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    System.exit(1)
}
```

Alternative solutions are:

1. Use [JMeter Maven plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/), if you add the following execution declaration to your pom.xml file:

   ```
   <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
   <execution>
       <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
       <goals>
           <goal>results</goal>
       </goals>
   </execution>
   ```

   the Maven plugin will mark the job as failed if there will be test failures and Gitlab-CI will "catch" this and mark your build as failed
2. You can also consider running your JMeter test using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as the wrapper, Taurus provides flexible and powerful [pass/fail criteria subsystem](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) where you can set the success and/or failure criteria for your test and if they will not be met - Taurus will return non-zero exit status code which will be sufficient for marking the build as failed by Gitlab-CI